# Ckeditor 4 - how can I change the color of the link including underline?

Tags: html, css, ckeditor

When I try to change color of the link (as you [can do on demo page](http://ckeditor.com/demo#full)) then color of the text is changed but underline is still blue.

[image]

Is there any way to make Ckeditor to also change the color of underline too? I want to make Ckeditor to change the color of underline too by default without any movements from the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Here is my code:

```
  editor = CKEDITOR.inline(editable_text_element)

  # This event called when text is updated in current editor.
  editor.on 'change', ->
    links = iframe().find('a')
    links.each () ->
      current_link = $(this)
      links_children = current_link.children()

    # Our case is when <a> has only 1 child and this is <span>
    if links_children.size() is 1
      child = links_children.first()
      child_color = child.css('color')
      current_link_color = current_link.css('color')

      current_link.css('color': child_color) if current_link_color isnt child_color
```

This is not ideal but it works. I set color via style when text has changed.

Answer (score 2):

if you double click on the link a small popup window will open, there you found the Advance option(last tab)

Inside Advance option there is a field called style, you can mention `color:red` or `text-decoration:none` there.

This will solve your issue.

Comment: I want to make Ckeditor to change the color by default without any movements from the user. Your solution doesn't allow that, unfortunately.

Comment: this option is provided by Ckeditor. if you want to change the color permanently that you can edit  the Ck editor css.

Answer (score 1):

there is a property called `text-decoration-color`:

Example:

```
p {
    text-decoration: underline;
    -moz-text-decoration-color: red; /* Code for Firefox */
    text-decoration-color: red;
}
```

But! it is **not Supported** in current browsers:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-color

Comment: But is there any way to make Ckeditor to create this styling? Because as I see it doesn't do it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ckeditor , but unless it is doing some unique css hacks (like adding border-bottom to specified text) - which I'm pretty sure this editor doesn't do, you won't be able to do that. The only option is completely removing the underline, as @Roy suggested, but you'll have to declare the CSS rules yourself if Ckeditor has no option for that